# My input in scanf is not working, process is returned and I don't get any output

Tags: c, recursion, scanf, fibonacci

The Fibonacci series is not obtained on running this program. The whole process terminates after giving input in `scanf`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fibonacci(int);

int main()
{
    int n, i = 0, c;
    printf("Print the fibonacci series");
    scanf("%d", n);
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", fibonacci(i));
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n = 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n = 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already been told in [Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168202/my-input-in-scanf-is-not-working-process-is-returned-and-i-dont-get-any-output/64168223#64168223), `scanf` expects an address for each format specifier. So, if format specifier `%d` is provided, the address of an integer is expected: `scanf` will write the value there.

If `n` is the variable containing the integer, `&n` is its address. Passing something that is not an address causes trouble: it is *undefined behavior* and will likely cause a segmentation fault.

---

There are also some problems in your Fibonacci generator. I suppose you want to print the *n-th* number in the sequence, but you iterate *`n`* times calling `fibonacci()` function (which only returns the last value) **always with parameter `i`**, which value is 0.

In `fibonacci` function you try to check for the exit conditions, but **pay attention**:

```
if (n = 0)
    return 0;
```

doesn't check the value of `n`; it **performs an assignment** (the value of `n` will be 0 and the condition will be false). So it will proceed to the next "test"

```
if (n = 1)
    return 1;
```

It is an assignment as well, 1 is assigned to `n` so the condition is true and **1 is returned**. That's why you see 1 `n` times.

---

### In order to make it work

- correct the *`scanf` issue*
- pass `c` to `fibonacci()`
- correct the function so that the value is tested (`==` instead of `=`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fibonacci(int);

int main()
{
    int n, c;
    printf("Print the fibonacci series\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", fibonacci(c));
    }
    return 0;
}
int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2));
}
```

Comment: You can remove `i = 0,` and `i++;` which serve no purpose.

Comment: Thanks @Stef, you are correct. I didn't put enough effort in cleaning the clutter.

Answer (score 4):

With scanf you need the give the address of the variable.

```
   scanf("%d",&n); <= need to give the address of the integer
```

You can find some examples here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: I did it but there is another problem now i am getting 5 times 1 if i am giving the input to be 5 and not the fibonacci series plz help @Robert

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `&` sign in the `scanf` statement, and also , I think you got confused with the assignment operator `=` and logical equal `==`, in the Fibonacci function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fibonacci(int);

int main()
{
    int n, i = 0, c;
    printf("Print the fibonacci series");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", fibonacci(i));
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int fibonacci(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
     else
        return (fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2));
}
```